# mail sending successful but email can not reach in mailbox using smtp server in java

Tags: java, smtp

I am sending email using smtp server. While sending **`" mail,sending successful but email can not reach in mailbox "`**, neither in spam nor in Inbox.

Comment: Code please, otherwise cant help.

Comment: refer this question [java-email-content-is-empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107807/java-email-content-is-empty)...

Comment: show us what u've tried

Comment: actually just now I tried email send to only domain except gmail and yahoo

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30006337/1057230). Hopefully it helps :-) But we definitely need code to help further.