# Unable to send email using javamail api in linux

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-mail

Here is my code it works on Windows machine but it does not work in linux...
its not throwing any exception.. on linux

```
public void alert(String recipient, String subject , String error){

    final String username = customize.getString("alertSenderEmail");
    final String password = customize.getString("alertSenderPassword");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp1.qualitykiosk.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    session.setDebug(true);

    String[] receivers = recipient.split(","); 
    for (String receiver : receivers) {

            try {


                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(receiver));
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setText(error);

                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                //throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }

}
```

Error --:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp1.qualitykiosk.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 ESMTP ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp1.qualitykiosk.com", port: 25

EHLO
501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
HELO
501 Syntax: HELO hostname
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp1.qualitykiosk.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 ESMTP ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp1.qualitykiosk.com", port: 25

EHLO
501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
HELO
501 Syntax: HELO hostname
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp1.qualitykiosk.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 ESMTP ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp1.qualitykiosk.com", port: 25

EHLO
501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
HELO
501 Syntax: HELO hostname
```

Comment: Please have a look at this post, regarding [simple email program with attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30006337/1057230). Hopefully it might will help you somewhat, in your endeavour :-)

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if Java/JavaMail cannot detect your current hostname. Use property `mail.smtp.localhost` to explicitly specify the hostname for `EHLO`/`HELO`.

From https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html :

> `mail.smtp.localhost` `String`
>   Local host name used in the SMTP HELO or EHLO command. Defaults to `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`. Should not normally need to be set if your JDK and your name service are configured properly.

As a more long term solution, you might want to find out why `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` is (apparently) not returning a hostname.

Comment: Note that if you're using the "smtps" protocol to access SMTP over SSL, all the properties would be named "mail.smtps.*".  
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html